# Is it possible to mount docker volume between two physical instances?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I’m trying to understand the swarm and volumes in scale. I followed the https://docs.docker.com/get-started until the end and everything was clear and working as expected. Now I want to do the same thing (have two nodes, **1 manager**, **1 worker**) but on my physical devices. Let’s say I have two computers on the same network or two AWS instances.

I tried to set it up between my two computers on the local network, but it seems that the manager’s IP is responding to the manager nodes and worker’s IP to worker nodes. Also, the Redis is not working on the worker’s IP.

I think it should be possible, but I can’t find an article where they are doing a similar thing.

I mean there should be a way, I don’t think that companies are running all their Docker containers on the same server (AWS instances)

P.S.: I'm using all the same files and setups provided in the link above.

Comment: It seems that the problem is coming from my MacBook, which is blocking all the connections which are necessary for the Docker Swarm to work properly!